# AsyncSocket delegate method called incorrectly?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets, asyncsocket

I'm transferring a reasonably large image over a local network from an iPhone to Mac using the AsyncSocket class. In the header the didReadData delegate method is declared as below:

```
/**
 * Called when a socket has completed reading the requested data into memory.
 * Not called if there is an error.
**/
- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag;
```

It says this method will be called when the socket has **completed** reading the data. However this method is called many times, each time data length increasing. How am I meant to know when the download is finished? Am I meant to send the length of the data in the first few bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That delegate method will indeed be called when the socket has completed reading the data. The missing part of the equation is telling the `AsyncSocket` *when* the received data is complete. It has no understanding of the data you're trying to receive, you have to tell it -- as you alluded to in your final question.

This is where `AsyncSocket` really shines. You can indeed send the image prefixed by its length and let the class work its magic. Your code would look something like the following.

```
[sock readDataToData:[AsyncSocket CRLFData] withTimeout:0 tag:kLengthTag];
```

In your delegate method:

```
- (void)onSocket:(AsyncSocket *)sock didReadData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag {
    if (tag == kLengthTag) {
        NSUInteger length = /* read length out of nsdata */;
        [sock readDataToLength:length withTimeout:0 tag:kImageTag];
    } else if (tag == kImageTag) {
        /* hurray, you have your image! */
    }
}
```

Of course, if you are transferring reasonably large images, you may want to keep track of your progress. For this purpose, there is the `-[AsyncSocket progressOfReadReturningTag:bytesDone:total:]` instance method. There's also the `-[id<AsyncSocketDelegate> onSocket:didReadPartialDataOfLength:tag:]` delegate method.

Comment: This would be great if it worked, since implementing this, the `didReadData` only sometimes is called for the length, and is never called for the image.

Comment: For some crazy reason the length has to be an int, not a NSUInteger, even though I've used NSUInteger everywhere else because thats what NSData uses.

Comment: Perhaps you could share a code sample with us. It is extraordinarily unlikely that the use of `NSUInteger` (a typedef for either `long` or `int`, depending on your platform) is the problem; it is more likely an issue with your parsing elsewhere.

Comment: It wasn't working so I tried to set the length to 5. And got gradually bigger until I reached the actual length if the data bring transmitted, and everything worked perfectly. Seeing as putting length directly in the code is an int I changed the type to int and it worked. Changed it back to NSUInteger and it didn't work.